# How do I retrieve data from SQL database?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, resultset, indexoutofboundsexception

So here is my connection. It successfully works.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Gear?user=root&password=admin");
Statement st = c.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Weapons");
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
```

Here is my code to retrieve the data.

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "Id", "Name", "Style", "DPS"};    
int rowcount = 0;

if (rs.last()) //finds out how many rows there are
{
  rowcount = rs.getRow();
  rs.beforeFirst();
}

String[][] data = new String[rowcount][columns.length]; //data storage array

while(rs.next())
{
    for( int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 1; j <= md.getColumnCount();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(data[i][j] = rs.getString(j)); //add the record
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my table data:

> ID, Weapon Name, Style, DPS
>
> 1, Noxious Staff, Magic, 1000
>
> 2, Ascension Crossbow, Ranged, 1200
>
> 3, Tetsu Katana, Melee, 950

I'm getting an error saying that it is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` out of bounds. How do I fix this error?

Comment: try starting j with 0 and let it run to  j < md.getColumnCount() I would btw precompute the value of  md.getColumnCount() and store it somewhere. This is faster :)

Comment: It would say that it is `java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.`

Comment: Is all your table columns are of string type? or iD is `integer` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be the way you are grabbing the column value. When you ask for it, you need to provide the name of the column, not an index numerical value.

Like this: `rs.getString("Id")`

Just do this multiple times to get each column value in the rows. Hope this helps!

Comment: It still says it's out of bounds when I put `for( int j = 1; j < md.getColumnCount();j++)`.

Comment: @puretppc When you grab a row value, you should be asking for the name of that column, not a number. Like this `rs.getString("Column Name")`

Comment: I changed my answer, you need to be asking for column names, not a numerical identifier. If you are looking for a different value, then adjust what property of `rs` you are grabbing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code

```
for( int j = 0; j < columns.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(data[i][j] = rs.getString(j + 1)); //add the record
    }
```

While looking at your code i don't get the point of using **metadata**. You don't need to use it at all.